# To Monitor & Log home ISP Internet Uptime/ Downtime using a Router or similar (Non PC/ Mobile) devices?

Tags: networking, router, internet-connection, uptime

Is there a decent way to do this without depending on my Laptop/ Phone etc devices.

But using a Device such as the Router itself (IDEAL & PREFERABLE)  (Forward / outbound checks or Inbound from certain sites mentioned here)

https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1351974-monitor-internet-downtime/

Long shot:

I am wondering if an Amazon Fire Stick device / Alexa Echo Dot or something similar could be tasked to do it?

PS: Also, I wouldn't mind using PRTG (allows Free handling of less than 100 devices) but I can't keep it awake all the time.

But if it can extract some SNMP or similar data from my ROUTER and my Gigabit switch (Pro Curve) then I don't mind that either.

Comment: How about a remote ping monitor, such as that from https://www.thinkbroadband.com/broadband/monitoring/quality/list ?

Comment: Have you checked to see if your router already logs this information?

Comment: @DavidPostill - not by default. No such feature. Do you know if routers that test & log it?

Comment: @Tetsujin looking into it as suggested in yours as well as previous link I posted